# How to update a product in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a product that I want to edit. Please see the following code.

```php
public function update(ProductRequest $request, Product $product)
{
    $product->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $product->title = $request->title;
    $product->body = $request->body;
    $product->price = $request->price;

    if ($request->has('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(public_path('images/products'), $filename);
        $product->image = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    }
    $product->update();
    $product->categories()->sync($request->category);

    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

**product.blade.php**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('products.update', $product->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
.
.
.
```

Everything changes except the image. I tried it, but, I did not succeed. What's the solution? I want to update the image in the database.

OK, I go to database now, I changed in image to picture, then I go my project, and I tested this again.

But it did not event for me.

I changed

```
public function update(ProductRequest $request, Product $product)
```

To

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
```

Comment: Have you checked that $request->has('image') is true?

Comment: Yes, I checked that `$request->has('image')` is true.

Comment: How have you tried to debug it? Does `$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();` return the expected value?At a glance it seems you should be using `save()` instead of `update()`

Comment: I changed it but I see in database, the image did not change...

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi Can you post the blade template for the form being used to upload the images?

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi I have updated my answer. I suggest putting `dd($request->all())` at the top line of your `update(...)` method. Post the form and check the output, if the file is not included then change the first parameter of the update method from `ProductRequest $request` to `Request $request` using `Illuminate\Http\Request` and try it again. There could be something in your ProductRequest class that is causing a problem.

Comment: Please check this boilerplate. https://github.com/brnrajoriya/laravel-5-6-crud-operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a model, you should retrieve it, set any attributes you wish to update, and then call the  save method. See the updates section in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models).

```
public function update(ProductRequest $request, Product $product)
{
    $product->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $product->title = $request->title;
    $product->body = $request->body;
    $product->price = $request->price;
    
    if ($request->has('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(public_path('images/products'), $filename);
        $product->image = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    }
    $product->save();
    $product->categories()->sync($request->category);

    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

---

## Update 1

Assuming you have debugged the above and `$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName()` is returning the expected value, it's possible that you are using field whitelisting on your model and haven't added the **image** field to the whitelist. Make sure that **image** is  in the `$fillable` array on your model.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'title',
        'body',
        'price',
        ...
        'image'
    ];
```

---

## Update 2

If `$request->file('image')` is returning null then that would suggest your form is not submitting the files. Ensure your `<form>` element has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute included in the tag.

---

## Update 3

If your already including the required `enctype="multipart/form-data"` tags in the `<form>` element then I would suggest doing the following.

Place `dd($request->all());` at the top of your `update(ProductRequest $request, Product $product)` method. Post the form and check the output.

If the file is not included in the output, change from using **ProductRequest $request** to the default **Request $request** (`Illuminate\Http\Request`) and try it again. There could be something in your `ProductRequest` class that is causing a problem.

---

As a small critique, you could improve your code in the following ways.

・Use `hasFile()` instead of `has()`.

・Use `$product-image = $filename` instead of `$product->image = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();`.

```
public function update(ProductRequest $request, Product $product)
{
    $product->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $product->title = $request->title;
    $product->body = $request->body;
    $product->price = $request->price;

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(public_path('images/products'), $filename);
        $product->image = $filename;
    }
    
    $product->save();
    $product->categories()->sync($request->category);

    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

Comment: The image in database did not change.

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi You need to debug your method line by line to ensure that `$image` is returning a value. Is it possible that you have a whitelist (`protected $fillable = [];`) setup on the Product model and haven't added the `image` field to it?

Comment: I putted in Product.php already `protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title', 'body', 'image', 'price', 'slug', 'viewCount', 'commentCount'];`

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi In that case, please dump the filename value by adding `dd($request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName());` after the `$product->image = ...` line to ensure you are actually getting the expected data.

Comment: I get this error. `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null`

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi That would suggest your file is not being submitted by the form. Did you include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form>` element. This is required for posting files via a form.

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi There was no effect? What is the output of `dd($request->all());` ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your  has

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

property